# How to see LDAP errors generated from PHP

Tags: php, logging, ldap, debian

I'm trying to bind to a remote, third party LDAP server.  I can connect/bind/search just fine from the command line on my server, but PHP just gives the monumentally unhelpful error: "Cannot connect to server".

I've seen where I can set the log level, but I don't know where those errors actually get logged to.  Searching along the lines of "ldap [client] log location" returns results exclusively for ldap *servers*

How do I see the errors PHP generates when trying to bind?

If it matters, I'm using Debian.

**Edit**

Here's the relevant code:

```
public function auth($username,$password){
    $ims_config = $this->di()->get('config')->ims;
    $username = $this->filterUsername($username);

    $this->conn = ldap_connect($ims_config->url);
    if($this->conn){
        $rdn = str_replace('?', $username, $ims_config->bind_rdn);

        if(ldap_bind($this->conn,$rdn,$password)){
            $this->isAuthed = TRUE;
        }
    }
    return $this->isAuthed;
}
```

I have checked `$ims_config->url` and `$rdn`, and they are correct.

Comment: afaict, you *do* see the errors generated by the client, namely "Cannot connect to server". it's impossible to give you more information based on the info you provided: you should at least provide some code, where you try to access the ldap-server

Comment: The code is pretty basic, but I've added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty old question and the poster probably found the answer already, but for the sake of answering and completion, the [PHP LDAP technote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-error.php) explains how you can do this using `ldap_error($conn)` and `ldap_get_option($conn, LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE, $err)`.